# Define Container for SweetAlert to Gray-Mask

Tags: javascript, dom, sweetalert

I'm using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) to display a success or error for a structured JSON result.  The `swal` call is made from actions the users takes against a modal window already on top of the document window.  From a UX perspective, it is expected that SweetAlert would gray-out the modal window, however, because SweetAlert (and the calling Javascript) resides at the document level, the document window (and not the modal window) is grayed by SweetAlert.

Not only is it preferable to gray-out the modal window because this is where the action originated, but having the gray-mask applied to the element/container directly behind the SweetAlert allows it to stand out from the rest of the page.  In the picture below, you can see how the SweetAlert blends into the page without the gray-mask properly applied to whatever container is behind it.

(It should not matter, but to stem the inevitable question: the modal window is created using the [Kendo UI Window](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window) widget)

I do not see any configurable options in the SweetAlert API which would allow me to pass in an optional container for gray-masking.  Is there any known way to tell SweetAlert which container it should use to gray-mask?

[image]

Comment: Would prefer a solution using the SweetAlert API, however, it doesn't seem to be in the cards just yet.  In the interim, I've added the BlockUI jQuery plugin to do what I need.  Just before the `swal({...});` call, I have called `.block({ message: null })` on the container behind the SweetAlert modal.  To `.unblock()` the same element, it must be done in the callback function defined in the call to `swal`.  Be sure to configure SweetAlert with `allowEscapeKey: false` or else the user may press the ESC key to kill the SweetAlert without the callback being called.